# Golang iterate over map of interfaces

Tags: go, go-interface, go-map

I am trying to iterate over a map of interfaces in golang, it has the below structure, I am able to use for loop to iterate to a single level but couldn't go deep to get values of the interface.

> Yaml

```
steps:
  execute:
  - mvn : 1.9.3
    goals: 'clean install'
    concurrent: false
  - mvn : 1.9.3
    goals: 'dependency-check:check'
    concurrent: false
```

> Go

```
// reading a yaml file 
// trying to use "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" package

data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    for k, v := range m {
       // Trying to explore the data here
        fmt.Println("k:", k, "v:", v)

    }
```

Output of

```
fmt.Printf("--- m:\n%v\n\n", m)
```

looks like below

```
map[steps:map[execute:[map[concurrent:false goals:clean install mvn:1.9.3] map[concurrent:false goals:dependency-check:check mvn:1.9.3]]]]
```

**My attempt**

```
for k, v := range m {
    fmt.Println("k:", k, "v:", v)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the Execute object and iterate over it you have to do a lot of type assertions like the answer given by @vooker.

Actually it's not recommended to use `map[interface{}]interface{}` for unmarshaling process. It should be unmarshalled to a concrete type as a struct.

From the YAML structure, it could be translated as a struct type like this:

```golang
type data struct {
    Steps struct {
        Execute []execute `yaml:"execute"`
    } `yaml:"steps"`
}

type execute struct {
    MVN        string `yaml:"mvn"`
    Goals      string `yaml:"goals"`
    Concurrent bool   `yaml:"concurrent"`
}
```

And from the structure, it is easier to access the unmarshalled data from the YAML.  For example, if you want to iterate over the "execute" object you could do something like this:

```golang
    var result data
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &result)
    fmt.Println(result) 

    // iterate over the slice of object
    for _, e := range result.Steps.Execute {
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println("mvn:", e.MVN)
        fmt.Println("goals:", e.Goals)
        fmt.Println("concurrent:", e.Concurrent)
    }
```

Try it on the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TbUts2_uiPB)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a tree of map[interface{}]interface{} and []interface{}, use the following code to walk the tree:

```
func walk(v interface{}) {
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        for i, v := range v {
            fmt.Println("index:", i)
            walk(v)
        }
    case map[interface{}]interface{}:
        for k, v := range v {
            fmt.Println("key:", k)
            walk(v)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

This code recurses down the structure and uses [type switches](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) to find the slices and maps.

Use it like this:

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
var m map[interface{}]interface{}
err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
walk(m)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/f_WOtU0ihVl)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean with that "value of m" as that doesn't look like any format I've seen in Go so I'll talk to a few situations: When the interfaces are probably types you know what they are vs when the interfaces could be anything and you aren't sure.

If there are only a couple of types that you know went into the map, you can do a [type switch](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) and handle each type individually. This would give you the opportunity to reference subfields and print them as well. If you always print the same info for the same type of objects, you could look into adding a `String() string` function to your structs which will make them implement the [`Stringer` interface](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17) and then you can print the object and your String() func will get called even if it's boxed as an interface.

If you're working with a library that's filling the map, or there's simply too big a diversity of the types in the map for a type switch to be reasonable, then you'll either want a generic solution such as a library like [spew](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew) or a custom solution written with [reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection).

Comment: Apologize, I should have made it more clear. I've edited the question. Thanks.